# Bot Framework: Can't get ActivityTypes.Typing to work.

Tags: botframework

I've been programming a lot with the MS Bot Framework but I can't seem to make this seemingly trivial part work: sending a Typing activity.

This fails every time:
[image]

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (if inside a dialog):

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;
    var activity2 = activity.CreateReply();
    activity2.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
    await context.PostAsync(activity2);
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

This is most likely because you are using `MakeMessage()` but not actually setting any of the fields it needs, you are only setting `Type`  so some property in the activity created is throwing the null object reference error.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion it seems is because of the lack of a CreateReply() on the IActivity or IMessageActivity interface. I have been converting my awaitables to instances of interface.

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon. This also does not work. Throws same Reference not sent to an instance... error.

Comment: nm, I finally traced down the issue and it had nothing to do with the MakeMessage vs CreateReply. It was that there was an IActivity logger trying to use the IActivity.Text property which was throwing an exception when the IActivity.ActivityType was Typing

Comment: yup that would do it too